# ruby on rails foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

basically what I am trying to do is use a foreign key. E.g. 144 which will return an object. I keep getting an error saying the record number cannot be found.

In the order show view.

(I have tested it and @order.cart_id is valid and does return a number. E.g. 144

```
<b>Order items:</b>
<%= @cart.get_order_cart(@order.cart_id) %>
```

In cart model, get_order_cart method

```
def get_order_cart(cart_id)
  cart = Cart.find(cart_id)
  cart.line_items.each do |item| 
    item.product.title
  end
end
```

Like I say though, this doesn't work. What is the problem please?
Thanks

Comment: little confused, is @cart the same cart as Cart.find(@order.cart_id)?

Comment: What do you expect it to do, precisely?

Comment: Your order might have a cart id, but does the carts table have a record with that id?  It sounds like it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ActiveRecord associations?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

Now, you can get your cart simply by

```
@cart = @order.cart
```

Comment: Thanks, the associations are there.

I have tried this code though it doesnt seem to work even though it appears correct

  <% [at]order.cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.product.title%>
  <% end%>

It fails when it says there is an undefined line_items method.
It works when I take out the [at]order and replace it with [at]cart but I need the association there.
Thanks

Comment: An undefined method line_items on which object? Is it on NilClass? It might be helpful if you post the code for your models as well.

Comment: line_items is not a method but an attribute.
In cart.rb
has_many :line_items


I will post the models now